# PATINDEX returning 0 on matching rexpresson

Tags: regex, t-sql

As far as I found out, T-SQL has a possibility to check for regular expressions, via 
PATINDEX.

My task is simple: I get a telecom-Type (phone for example). On a mapping table, a regex to validate this type is saved. So before saving, I'd like to check this regex.

So easy done:

```
  -- Check the regular expression for phone 
  DECLARE  @regExp  nvarchar(255);

  SELECT   @regExp = tt.ValidationRegex
  FROM     Core.TelecomType tt
  WHERE    tt.Code =  @DEFAULT_PHONE_TYPE;
```

Sadly, this always returns 0, even with wildcards with tries like this:

```
  SET @regExp = CONCAT('%', @regExp, '%');
  SET @regExp = CONCAT(@regExp, '%');
  SET @regExp = CONCAT('%', @regExp );
```

On RegExr and oracle-side, the values seem to match, so is this a problem on the T-SQL? If yes, is there a workarround for this?

Thanks in advance

Matthias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, sorry. `PATINDEX` doesn't let you match a regular expression, it works with the same kinds of patterns that are used with `LIKE`.

A quote from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx):

> `PATINDEX` works just like `LIKE`, so you can use any of the wildcards. You do not have to enclose the pattern between percents. `PATINDEX('a%', 'abc')` returns `1` and `PATINDEX('%a', 'cba')` returns `3`.
>   Unlike `LIKE`, `PATINDEX` returns a position, similar to what `CHARINDEX` does.

If you need regular expression matching in T-SQL, you'll have to rely on a custom CLR function/procedure. You can also check [this](http://www.pettijohn.com/2010/08/regular-expressions-in-sql-2008-r2.html) to see if you can use it.