# SQL Server: extracting $#,### from a string

Tags: sql-server, regex, substring, sql-server-2016, patindex

I'm trying to extract a dollar value from a string using a mixture of substrings, charindexes, and patindexes. I can seem to extract the `$###,###` pattern from all string except when it falls at the end of the string.

Here is some code with test cases:

```
CREATE TABLE #TMP 
(
    string VARCHAR(50)
)
GO

INSERT INTO #TMP
VALUES ('I have $4,000'),
       ('$44,450is what I have'),
       ('this $600 is what I have now'),
       ('$5 cause I am broke'),
       ('I have $10,000,000,000 '),
       ('No Money Here')
GO

SELECT 
    *,
    SUBSTRING(string, 
              CHARINDEX('$', string), 
              PATINDEX('%[^0-9,]%', SUBSTRING(string, CHARINDEX('$', string) + 1, 80000))) AS Result
FROM 
    #TMP

DROP TABLE #TMP
GO
```

Results:

[image]

SQL Server version:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) (KB3182545) - 13.0.4001.0 (X64)
```

Comment: I'm using Version Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) (KB3182545) - 13.0.4001.0 (X64)

Comment: Hi i doesn't work because your $4.000 it's at the end off line i think it's way for looking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add an x (or any non-numeric character) to every instance of `string`:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    SUBSTRING(
        string + 'x', 
        CHARINDEX('$',string + 'x'), 
        PATINDEX('%[^0-9,]%',SUBSTRING(string + 'x',CHARINDEX('$',string + 'x')+1, 80000))
    ) AS Result
FROM 
    #TMP
```

Comment: Simple. What would be more efficient? The case statement or adding the x?

Comment: I feel like using `LEN()` would be worse for performance but probably not in any human-measurable way.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i think this solution can be work :

```
CREATE TABLE #TMP (
    string varchar(50)
)
GO

INSERT INTO #TMP
VALUES
     ('I have $4,000')
    ,('$44,450is what I have')
    ,('this $600 is what I have now')
    ,('$5 cause I am broke')
    ,('I have $10,000,000,000')
    ,('No Money Here')
GO

SELECT 
    *,
    PATINDEX('%[^0-9,]%',SUBSTRING(string,CHARINDEX('$',string)+1, LEN(string))),
    SUBSTRING(
        string, 
        CHARINDEX('$',string), 
        CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9,]%',SUBSTRING(string,CHARINDEX('$',string)+1, LEN(string))) = 0  THEN  LEN(string) -1 ELSE PATINDEX('%[^0-9,]%',SUBSTRING(string,CHARINDEX('$',string)+1, LEN(string))) END
    ) AS Result
FROM 
    #TMP

DROP TABLE 
  #TMP
GO
```

The way it's due too the PATINDEX function return 0 if the pattern was at the end of string.

But i didn't know what your find if you receive multiple amount in 1 string 
like : helo i have $20 now but yesterday i have $100

For more information : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Other post : [PATINDEX returning 0 on matching rexpresson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28194419/patindex-returning-0-on-matching-rexpresson)

Comment: This worked. I could've been more clear about my constraints - There will only be one dollar amount in these lines.

Thanks!